# Why am I getting questions with 3 or more answers when I instant load new questions?

Tags: support, tags, questions

Whenever I load new questions from the Chrome browser pinned tab of stackoverflow.com/questions/php it loads questions with 2 or 3+ answers or downvotes.

It seems like I am receiving messages too late when I load new questions instantly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php may show the latest *active* [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) questions, if that's the last selected tab (thanks @AndrewT.). *Active* means questions which have recently received new answers and/or edits to answers or the question itself; this includes old(er) questions.

To only see new questions, select the newest tab: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php?sort=newest

[image]

Comment: Not Satisfied But Thanks. Not satisfied because the tab is pinned from last 10 days. and this occurs only now

Comment: @TarangP actually, the tagged questions page (and all pages that list questions, except search page which uses 'relevance' by default) use the last chosen filter. This means that OP might have changed the filter once to 'active' elsewhere, then the pinned tab perhaps got refreshed and changed to 'active' instead.